# How to Return 3 values / substitutions of values

Tags: c#

Hi I'm creating a program that holds three arrays one for the persons last name, one for the points scored and one for the player number, now I've got all the arrays and everything done but I'm not sure as to how to return the 3 new arrays from my deletemethod so that I can pass it into my playerdelete method and I am also not sure on how to sub the values in the if statements. Also I can't use objects.

any help or guidance would be appreciated

```
    static Int32[] ProcessDelete(Int32[] playerNumbers, ref Int32 playerCount, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints)
        {
            Int32[] newArray = new Int32[playerNumbers.Length]; String[] newArray2 = new String[playerLastName.Length]; Int32[] newArray3 = new Int32[playerPoints.Length];

            int index = 0;
            int index2 = 0;
            int index3 = 0;
            int r = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int t = 0;
            while (index < playerNumbers.Length && index2 < playerLastName.Length && index3 < playerPoints.Length)
            {
                if (index != playerCount) { newArray[r] = playerNumbers[index]; }
                {

                }
                if (0 != 1) { newArray[0] = playerNumbers[0]; }
                {

                }
                if (0 != 1)
                {
                    newArray[0] = 12; //the value of playerNumbers[0]}


                }
                index++;
                if (index2 != playerCount) { newArray2[r] = playerLastName[index2]; }
                {
                }


                if (0 != 1) { newArray2[0] = playerLastName[0]; }
                {

                }
                if (0 != 1)
                {
                    newArray2[0] = null; 
                }
                index2++;
                if (index3 != playerCount) { newArray3[r] = playerPoints[index3]; }
                {

                }
                if (0 != 1) { newArray3[0] = playerPoints[0]; }
                {

                }
                if (0 != 1)
                {
                    newArray3[0] = 12; 


                }
                index3++;
            }
                return newArray;



            }


        static void DeletePlayer(Int32[] playerNumbers, String[] playerLastName, Int32[] playerPoints, ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
        {
            int player;// Player number to delete
            int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
            if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
            {

                player = GetPositiveInteger("\nDelete Player: please enter the player's number");
                playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(player, playerNumbers, playerCount);


               if (playerindex != -1)
                {

                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: Number - {0}, Name - {1}, Points - {2}", playerNumbers[playerindex], playerLastName[playerindex], playerPoints[playerindex]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Succesfully Deleted");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        ProcessDelete(playerNumbers, ref playerCount, playerLastName, playerPoints);
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: player not found");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nDelete Player: the roster is empty");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use objects... I feel very, very sorry for you. You can't use any? Like not even `Tuple`? You could always have 3 `out`parameters

Comment: `I can't use objects` I think you may be using the wrong language then

Comment: @Jonesy Or it's a homework.... a very odd homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is homework, since otherwise, the "can't use objects" makes no sense.

Having said that, you can either return an array of arrays, and then simply use 
`array_of_arrays[0]` to indicate the first and so on, or you assuming you know the sizes in advance, you can probably return one array, and do the math to find your indexing yourself (either all of the first array, then all of the second,etc, or one of each ... it'll look like : 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 ... or 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3... , where the number indicate to which array the value belongs )

Answer (score 0):

You could try using only a single array of strings (or even a list) condense the values for each player into a comma (or other char[]) separated string (eg - "Billy,Barty,42,12"). Then simply split each string (and cast/convert as needed) into instance variables each time you need to work with them. When you're ready to delete a player just remove the one entry from the collection.

```
List<string> Player = new List<string>
{
    "Billy,Barty,42,12",
    "Jeffy,Jones,12,35",
    "Blueberry,Hill,43,5" // sorry...bad joke reference
}();
```

then to work with a player

```
static void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    DoSomethingWithPlayer(Player[1]) // Jeffy Jones from the example
}

static void DoSomethingWithPlayer(string player)
{
    string[] p = player.Split((char)','); // create an instance array representing the player
    string firstName = p[0];
    string lastName = p[1];
    int playerNumber = int.TryParse(p[2]);
    int playerPoints = itn.TryParse(p[3]);

    // some code to work with this player or call methods on this player
    // the collection 'p' is an instance that goes away after this method completes
}
```

If you need to update a player's data, create a new string with the new data and replace the existing element in the List<> (or array)

```
string newFirstName = "Blueberry";
string newLastName = "Jones";
string newPlayerNumber = "55";
string newPlayerPoints = "99";

string newPlayerData = newFirstName + "," +
    newLastName + "," +
    newPlayerNumber + "," +
    newPlayerPoints;

Player[2] = newPlayerData
```

You could even use these comma separated values to read/write a .csv file containing all your player data without objectifying ;)
Its a bit ugly, but without objects your options are a little limited.